# How to perform unit test for template driven form in angular

Tags: angular

I want to perform unit test for template driven form, I have created simple template driven form, can anyone please help me to write and execute  test cases.
How to write test cases for seperate input fields.

I want to write and execute test cases for my input fields. How to write test cases for this form input fields.

comp.html

```
<form #newUserForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newUserForm)">
        <mat-card class="example-card">
          <h3 class="color" id="num">Login form</h3>
          <p class="error-message" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</p>
          <mat-card-content class="login-container">
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input
                matInput
                type="text"
                placeholder="userName"
                [(ngModel)]="name"
                name="name"
                required
                #userName="ngModel"
              />
              <mat-error *ngIf="userName.invalid && userName.touched">
                <mat-error *ngIf="userName.errors?.required">
                User name is required!
                </mat-error>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input
                matInput
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                required
                [(ngModel)]="password"
                name="password"
                #userPassword="ngModel"
                [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
              />
              <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
                <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
                </button>
              <mat-error *ngIf="!userPassword.valid && userPassword.touched">
                Password is required!
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-card-content>
          <button
            mat-raised-button
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            [disabled]="!newUserForm.form.valid"
          >
            Register
          </button>&nbsp;
          <!-- <button
            mat-raised-button
            color="primary"
            type="button"
            (click)="newUserForm.reset()"
          >
            Reset
          </button> -->
        </mat-card>
      </form>
```

comp.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  hide = true;
  name: string;
  password: any;
  errorMessage: string;
  form:NgForm;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.valid) {
      console.log(form.value);
      this.userService.loginPage(form.value).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          if (data) {
            console.log(data);
            // this.userService.updateLoginData(data.message);
            this.router.navigate(["infohub"]);
          } else {
            // this.errorMessage = data.message;
            console.log(data);
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

comp.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
// import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';


describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
          [{
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent
          },])
      ],
      providers: [UserService],
    })
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);

    component = fixture.componentInstance; 

    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.errorMessage'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
    // .compileComponents();
    it('should display original errorMessage', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(el.textContent).toContain(component.errorMessage);
  });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // it('should create', () => {
  //   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  // });




});
```

Comment: Add your code .

Comment: Check this:https://angular.io/guide/testing#use-a-page-object

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama I have added my code.